# How to split models.py to serapate files w/o double import trap in Django

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have one big file models.py with a lot of classes inside and want to split to separate files in models subdirectory. My current project's structure is:

```
project
├── core
|   ├── settings
|   |   └── base.py
|   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── urls.py
|   ├── models.py
|   ├── views.py
|   └── wsgi.py
├── members
|   ├── migrations
|   ├── templates
|   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── forms.py
|   ├── models.py
|   ├── urls.py
|   └── views.py
├── templates
|   ├── pages
|   |   └── register.html
|   └── base.html
└── manage.py
```

I'm trying to split members/models.py to extended structure like:

```
├── members
|   ├── models
|   |   ├── __init__.py
|   |   ├── account.py
|   |   └── blabla.py
|   ├── migrations
|   ├── templates
|   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── forms.py
|   ├── urls.py
|   └── views.py
```

Python 2.7, Django 1.9 and django-allauth on board so in account.py I have 2 classes:

`class MyUserManager(UserManager)` and `class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin)`.

In models/**init**.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from account import *
from blabla import *
```

In settings `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'members.Account'`

All classes in models have `app_label = 'members'`.

`members/__init__.py` is empty

I have got this issue:

```
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'account_groups' models in application 'members':
<class 'members.models.account.Account_groups'> and <class 'models.account.Account_groups'>.
```

Any ideas how to avoid it?

Thanks.

**ADDED:**

```
DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.vk',
    'django_migration_fixture',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'tz_detect',
]

PROJECT_APPS = [
    'core',
    'admin',
    'members',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + PROJECT_APPS
```

Comment: add your settings.INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: See http://paltman.com/breaking-apart-models-in-django/

Comment: @kedar unfortunately it does't works, same issue

Comment: Maybe it is some kind of import problem. your `from account import *` also imports all imports in the `account` package. Maybe try to use the `__all__` variable in your account.py to only export the models?

Comment: @TimSchneider thanks Tim, but it doesn't works too. I found solution and will explain how to solve in self answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think this issue connects with allauth internal models.
I fixed it just created new app named `acc` and insert both allauth classes to models.py in this app.

in settings now:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'acc.Account'

PROJECT_APPS = [
    'acc',
    'core',
    'admin',
    'members',
]
```

Now I can split models.py from members to models subdirectory with separate files and it works well w/o runtime error.